# returning summaries of linear models using lapply

Tags: r, lapply

Can anyone explain why the following lapply function does not work, and a possible alternative that does not involve a for-loop.

```
DV1 <- rnorm(20, 10, 3)
DV2 <- rnorm(20, 8, 3)
DV3 <- rnorm(20, 9, 3)
group <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 2, length.out = 20)
df <- data.frame(group, DV1, DV2, DV3)
```

I would like to perform analyses on multiple outcome variables. In this example I created a list of outcome variables to pass into a lm function. Now my understanding is that lapply applies a function to a list and return a list. So why can't it give me a list of three `summary(lm())` objects, each of which is a list? Is there any way to do what I am trying to do with one of the apply family of functions?

```
cols <- list("DV1", "DV2", "DV3")

lapply(cols, function (x) summary(lm(x ~ group, data = df)))
```

Comment: `summary(lm(cbind(DV1, DV2, DV3) ~ group, data = df)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
forms <- paste(cols, ' ~ group')
lapply(forms, lm, data = df)
```

Or if you want to just print summaries rather than save output:

```
lapply(forms, function(x) summary(lm(x, data = df)))
```

Comment: thank you @David_B, I like this. So what was it about my version that `lapply` didn't like? I'm trying to work out some rules for what i can and can't do.

Comment: @llewmills In your version you pass the formula `x ~ group` to `lm`. Thus, it looks for a column `x` in `df`.

Comment: Yes, you have to construct the formula outside `lapply`.  The other answers are correct that this isn't the most efficient solution when you are using `lm`, although it is a more general solution; you can use it with `glm`, `polr`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for a loop. `lm` handles multiple dependent variables elegantly and (more important) efficiently:

```
summary(lm(cbind(DV1, DV2, DV3) ~ group, data = DF))
summary(lm(sprintf("cbind(%s) ~ group", paste(cols, collapse = ",")), data = DF))
```

Comment: Thank you @Roland, haven't seen `sprintf` before. This is why I love Stack Exchange.